# Teradata : Teradata not taking table-name for query

Tags: sql, teradata, subquery

I am working on Teradata SQL query, and in that query I am performing a join. Unfortunately, terradata is not accepting the table name as it is because there is a `.` or `period` in table name.

Query :

```
Insert TEST (NAME) VALUES((
sel
 smallname||' '||bigName
 ,upper(smallname)
 ,upper(bigName)
from domain.sourceTable as a
join  domain2.destinationtable as b on b.someId=a.otherId))
```

Error log :

```
5628: Column smallname not found in domain.a or domain2.b
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas.

Comment: `sel`? cut and paste error?

Comment: @jarlh : sel is `select`. That is the error shown below...Nothing else...

Comment: @jarlh : Shouldn't it search for columns in domain.sourceTable instead of just domain, that's what I am wondering or am I wrong?

Comment: Both tables should be searched. Have you tried qualifying the columns, e.g. `a.smallname`? However, your insert is a bit odd, since you select 3 columns but only one is expected.

Comment: @jarlh : I will make that correction to remove the 2 names. But why are the tables not getting searched? I meant the error.

Comment: @jarlh : Is there someway to combine the name and someName and insert it into one column, that's what I am trying to do actually.

Comment: What do you mean by *combine*, concatenate like your example or `UNION`?

Comment: @dnoeth : Concatenate data from 2 columns and insert it into one column.  Do you know why Teradata is checking the table name in wrong manner and ignoring the name after a dot? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `VALUES` clause as you don't insert a single row:

```
Insert into TEST (NAME) 
select
 smallname||' '||bigName
from domain.sourceTable as a
join  domain2.destinationtable as b on b.someId=a.otherId
```

Comment: I can access the database tomorrow morning, limited time period. Kindly give me time till I reply tomorrow.